# Getting started With Animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-studio, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

I want to create a live wallpaper with a space kind of theme to it. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction of how to do this.  I was also wondering if I were to make a moving galaxy animation the main attraction, what are the possibilities of creating it, can I create it directly in android studio using OpenGL or drawing it to the Canvas using the View or SurfaceView classes? Or do I have to make an image in a program like Photoshop, or Blender, or do I have to make an animated gif in anyone of those programs as well or even a Sprite sheet. I am just looking for something along the lines to get me started and I am really wondering what would be the best way for creating an image like that (The animated Galaxy).

Comment: [Check](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-live-wallpapers-on-android--mobile-9516)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: How is your moving galaxy animation will be? (is it just moving an image or like walking a man / make a bird fly with flapping?)

Comment: @ondermerol Like walking a man or making a bird fly